# Дублировать каждый следующий элемент строки

Tags: javascript

У меня есть функция:

```
export const repeatString = (str = '') => {

}
repeatString('MjtkuBovqrU')
```

Как сделать, чтобы строка, которая введена при запуске функции, возвращала новую строку, где каждая буква по порядку будет умножаться на свою позицию по порядку? Спасибо

Comment: Что такое `каждый следующий ` символ ?

Comment: @MBo, Типа каждая последующая буква имеет умножаться на то число, которым она стоит по порядку. M-jj-ttt...

Comment: Информацию добавьте, отредактировав вопрос

Comment: @MBo уже изменил

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
console.log('StacK'.split('').map((a, i) => a.repeat(i + 1)).join('-'));
```

Comment: Большое спасибо)))

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял то можно так:

```js
console.log('MjtkuBovqrU'.split('').reduce((acc, i) => {
    return acc += i + i
}, []))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const doubleChar = (str) => str.split("").map(c => c + c).join("");
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]